# Static files and ajax requests with webpack

Tags: reactjs, package, packaging, webpack, static-files

How to include static files/folder (*.json, images, etc.) using webpack into package? The access to the files will be through ajax requests in runtime.

Comment: Example:

<img src="./images/USER_STATUS.png" />

where USER_STATUS is some variable which can have different values like disabled (./images/disabled.png), enabled (./images/enabled.png), pending, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

You don't bundle the json or images. You call them from the server. With a node server it would look something like this. Your file path would be relative to ui-dist/.

```
    'use strict';

    var Emitter = require('primus-emitter');
    var express = require('express');
    var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
    var path = require('path');
    var Primus = require('primus');
    var socketCallBack = function(socket){ require('./mainsocket.js')(socket); };
    var port = Number(process.env.PORT || 3700);

    //console.log('Port: ' + port);

    var app = express();
    app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'ui-dist', 'img', 'favicon.ico')));

    var server = app.listen(port);
    var sio = new Primus(server, { transformer: 'websockets', parser: 'JSON' });
    sio.use('emitter', Emitter);

    var newPrimusOptions = false;
    if (newPrimusOptions) {
        sio.library();
        sio.save('./ui-src/lib/primus/primus.js');
    }

    sio.on('connection', socketCallBack);

    app.use('/', express.static('ui-dist'));
    app.get('/', function(req, res){ res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html', [], null); });
```

Comment: Not exactly what I'm looking for. I've been expecting webpack has some configuration where you can simple include folder with static content.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve that using a webpack plugin that copies a specific content to the build folder.

https://github.com/kevlened/copy-webpack-plugin

In your webpack.config file you do something like:

```
plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        { 
           from: 'from/file.txt', to: 'to/file.txt' 
        },
    ]),
],
```